# Select option tag in HTML

Tags: html, html-select

There is html code to select options without closing option tag and its working fine.

```
<div><div class="select-wrapper">
        <select  name="adult">
          <option value="none" />Adults
          <option value="0" />0 Adults
          <option value="1" />1 Adults
          <option value="2" />2 Adults
          <option value="3" />3 Adults
          <option value="4" />4 Adults
          <option value="5" />5 Adults
          <option value="5" />5+ Adults
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="select-wrapper">
        <select  name="kids">
          <option value="none" />Children
          <option value="0" />0 Children
          <option value="1" />1 Children
          <option value="2" />2 Children
          <option value="3" />3 Children
          <option value="4" />4 Children
          <option value="5" />5 Children
          <option value="5+" />5+ Children
        </select>
      </div></div>
```

I know it is bad style to write  but I want to know any scenarios where it can break or will not work?

Comment: Refer this http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/optional-html-end-tags-when-to-include-them.htm

Comment: @ShaiAharoni This use of the syntax is documented in the W3C HTML reference. It's valid.

Comment: @MikeW it isn't. Have you tried to validate this markup?

Comment: @Pavlo have you read the W3C HTML reference on the subject?

Comment: @MikeW I have. It says the only allowed content for `<select>` is `<option>` and `<optgroup>`, not text content. Here we have `<option value="none"></option>Children` that's why it fails to validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to close `option` tag right away. Currently you have the following validation error:

> Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.

However, [according to the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-option-element) you may omit closing tag, it won't cause any problems:

```
<select>
    <option>Option One
    <option>Option Two
</select>
```

Additionally, "1 Adults" and "1 Children" isn't proper English.